# Text in transparent windows is not antialiased

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, translucency

Text in transparent windows ( AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(window, false) ) is not antialiased correctly,  and looks different then in opaque windows.

I'm using JDK 7.40.

Any idea how to workaround it?

In the program below the button text is not antialiased (correctly). Removing the setWindowOpaque() fixes the antialiasing.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;

public class TransparentFrame extends JFrame
{
    public TransparentFrame()
    {
        setUndecorated(true);
        AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);
        add(new JButton(new ExitAction()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new TransparentFrame();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ExitAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public ExitAction()
        {
            super("Exit");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Joop Eggen there is an issue with RenderingHints in xx_40, asked here two-three times last week, but some i*d*i*o*t* changed my tags, because Java haven't any bugs.

Comment: Except the SSCCE does not have anything to do with `RenderingHints` or custom painting.

Comment: Thanks Joop. I overrided paint() to inspect the graphics context, and couldn't find any difference in the RenderingHints or other attributes between the transparent and opaque mode.